# React button has reference after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap buttons, just click on that button `onClick` event will be triggered, after that if you scroll anywhere in the web app and then press enter the `onclick` event will be triggered,until clicking on other content that button has reference. help me to solve this, thanks in advance.

here is my react code:

```
reset = () =>{ console.log('triggers'); }
<Button onClick={() => { this.reset() }}>Reset</Button>
```

Comment: This is the focus and this is the expected behaviour. What else should happen?

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT unexpected behaviour.
When you click on a button it stays in focus until another element takes it. To change this behaviour you have to remove the focus from the button once it is clicked.

```
 <Button
    onClick={(event) => {
      this.reset();
      event.currentTarget.blur();
    }}
  >
    Reset
  </Button>
```